# Will "linux-image-grsec" be present on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kernel, grsec

I use the linux-image-grsec Kernel on Debian Sid and Arch, but I'd like to completely move to Ubuntu if Canonical supports that Kernel.

Does anyone have information on whether or not it will be supported? I could only find the following page, but it does not contain the Kernel image: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-grsec-base/6

Answer (score 1):

Canonical will not support that kernel, but it still can be installed.

`linux-grsec-base` package is already included in Ubuntu Xenial repositories.

It can be installed by

```
sudo apt install linux-grsec-base
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-grsec-base

Comment: As the description says, that's not a kernel - just some configuration, it needs an appropriate kernel installed.

Comment: You are correct.